# Regular Expression - Search for any text

Tags: regex, full-text-search, flv

If I have this regular expression: `(\&file=[A-Z]{4}\d{4}\/)`

but I have this search text: `&file=PSYC4534/SecretSuccess_512k.flv` where the file name for the .flv can be anything.

How can I complete the above expression to include ANY filename.flv?

Thanks

Comment: @MikeM No, that's a folder name, but it will always be four letters followed by four numbers.

Comment: Does the file path always use the Linux/Mac convention with a slash and never use the Windows convention with a back-slash?

Comment: @LeeMeador Yes. The file path will always be four letters, four numbers with a slash (MGMT5133/something.flv)

Comment: Next time please add more tags

Comment: Can the file be in a sub-directory? E.g. `&file=PSYC4534/somefolder/filename.flv `

Comment: @MikeM No, in this case it won't be.

Comment: @LeeMeador I'm not for sure. I have 400 HTML files and I noticed that notepad++ has a find feature for regular expressions.

Comment: So you are asking about a notepad++ regular expression. That's what we need to know. Different regex systems use, sometimes, slightly different syntax to enter the regexes. Some are more powerful. Some are less. That's why it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(\&file=[A-Z]{4}\d{4}\/).*?\.flv(\s|$)
```

`.*?\.flv(\s|$)` will match any character (except a newline) zero or more times, as few times as possible, until `.flv` appears followed by a space character or the end of string.

Comment: I think this would match `&file=PSYC4534/SecretSuccess_512k.flv-bob` too.

Comment: @LeeMeador: it indeed does. So does `&file=PSYC4534/Foo/Bar/SecretSuccess_512k.flv`, as does `&file=PSYC4534/.flv`, which are most likely unwanted matches.

Comment: @Lee Meador. That's fair criticism - I have adjusted the regex accordingly.

Comment: Change .* to .+ to get rid of the last one. Change . to [^/] to get rid of the the 1st one you mentioned. Change \b to $ to get rid of mine. But then you have what @Regexident used. We don't know about whether OP wants to go to subfolders, though.

Comment: 'Criticism' is such a harsh word. Just questions or observations.

Comment: @Lee Meador. We do know that - see the comments above. And there's nothing wrong with `.flv` as file name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\.flv` will match a sequence of one or more of the characters inside the square brackets and the extension. I put in the alpha and digits and the underscore. You may need some more but don't put in a dot/period.

Add this to the end of your expression `(\&file=[A-Z]{4}\d{4}\/)` but inside the parens.